# Follow button change text after click

Tags: buttons, data

im making an app that has a follow button for events. i would like to indicate how many followers there are but have limited room. what are your thoughts on the following:

[image: idea]

any ideas or suggestions? im stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to agree with what edgarator said. The follow/watch ability should reflect how many people are currently following/watching a piece of content. The only difference I would suggest is that they continue to show this meta data regardless of the users current state. An example of this can be found on Github where they have stared and forked projects..

Star (follow/watch)

[image: Github starred/watch featured not be watched]

Unstar (unfollow/unwatch)

[image: Github unstarred/unwatch featured not be unwatched]

Comment: i completely agree, however it is for a mobile app and it just gets too wide for the space available, it is certainly a compromise I will have to make, but I cant give any more room to this button

Answer (score 0):

This format has been used lately by many people... although it's inspired in the button used to share articles I think something like this could be useful.

[image: Follow Button]

The above state reflects an unfollowed event, and the state below a followed one.

---

Fundamentally, your approach can be improved with this one in the way that you show the amount of users that have already followed a specific event before the user actually clicks (showing that the event is popular) and after that, you enable the user to unfollow.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that there's no need to ever hide the number in either state. I don't want to get too much in to the UI side as we're here to talk UX but I'd do something like the below:

[image: Example of activate button]

Comment: Sorry - replace the word activate with follow - in both. Having a green tick with unfollow will confuse people!